# how does git pull <remote> work

Tags: git

Suppose I have a locol git repo and a remote repo called `hub`. Also suppose my local repo has `branch1`, and `branch2`, where as the remote repo has `branch1`, `branch2`, and `branch3`.

If I call

```
git pull hub
```

will this automatically merge both `hub/branch1` with `branch1` and `hub/branch2` with `branch2`, or will it only merge the corresponding remote branch into my currently checkedout branch? Also will it automatically create a new local `branch3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Question 1

> Will this automatically merge both hub/branch1 with branch1 and hub/branch2 with branch2, or will it only merge the corresponding remote branch into my currently checkedout branch?

The latter. Actually it is even a bit more complex, it will pull from the remote branch that you current branch is effectively tracking.

Suppose that you want local `branch1` to track hub `branch1`

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=hub/branch1 branch1
```

But nothing stops you from tracking another remote branch (**warning:** this will make your brain hurt)

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=hub/branch2 branch1
```

Local `branch1` now tracks remote `branch2` :D.

### Question 2

> Also will it automatically create a new local branch3?

No. This must be done explicitly.

If you are checking out a new branch, you can also make it track a remote branch by default:

```
git checkout -t hub/branch3
```

This will create a local `branch3` tracking the remote `branch3`.

---

But what if I **want** git to pull all branches?

```
git pull --all
```

Will bring all of your local branches **which are tracking** remote branches up to date. But it will not actually checkout new remote branches.

Comment: I think you mean the *latter* in your first sentence?

Answer (score 2):

`man git-pull`

says in the first sentence of 'DESCRIPTION':

"Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch."

First question: it will only merge the corresponding remote branch into your currently checkedout branch.

Second question: Branches are not automatically created.

Answer (score 0):

If you current branch is already tracking a remote branch, then the latter will be merged into the former. And it will not create any local branch.

The full form of the command is like this:

```
git pull remote remote-branch
```

And it always merges into your CURRENTly checked out local branch.

You can skip the last argument, if your CURRENT branch is already tracking a remote branch.
For instance if your currently checked local branch is `branch1`, and you've done a

```
git push hub branch1
```

in the past, then this is the case. So

```
git pull hub
```

actually means

```
git pull hub branch1
```

If you want to see where the remote branches are, without merging anything

```
git fetch
```

Answer (score 0):

`git pull hub` is equivalent to a combination of `git fetch hub` and `git merge`.

`git fetch hub` will update all `hub/*` branches. `git merge` will merge `hub/branch1` into `branch1`. (assuming you currently are on branch1.)

Nothing else is done. No other local branches are affected.

---

To be a bit more precise...

`git config remote.hub.fetch` will show what exactly is updated by `git fetch hub`. It probably is configured as

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/hub/*
```

This is telling `git fetc`h to update `hub/*`.

`git merge` will merge the configured upstream branch. You can show the configured upstream branch with `git branch -vv`. This will probably show something like

```
* branch1 1234567 [hub/branch1] message
```

This is telling `git merge` to merge `hub/branch1` into `branch1`